# How to reset a repo to another repo?

Tags: git

**Background**

I have two repos that are identical but have started to divert

- repo1 is original
- repo2 is new that was mirrored from repo1 (for new products)

I continue updated repo2 from repo1 to get bug fixes but it has been a while since I updated
and repo1 have grown to divert on certain areas of the code not all.

What I want is to start from the last update I made from repo1 but keep the new changes in repo2.

The fact is repo2 **has not** grown so much, that I could reset it to repo1 and reapply the changes of repo2 on top of it.

What is the best option here, should I mirror repo1 again, or should I revert all new changes in repo2?
Any suggestions?

Comment: My advice to keep  a copy of you change in the repo2 after that reset it to repo1 make the mirore again and finaly check the change done in the repo2 using the copy .

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
# in repo2 folder
git remote add repo1 <url>
git branch tmp
git reset --hard repo1/master
git merge tmp
```

Explanation:

- work in the "repo2" folder, which contains the code additions and updates
- add a remote that points to the old "repo1" repository
- create a `tmp` branch that contains the current snapshot of the repository
- reset hard the branch to "repo1"
- apply the diff, e.g. the changes from `tmp` to the current branch

Comment: I am getting this message

fatal: ambiguous argument 'repo1/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'


WHEN issuing the command
git reset --hard repo1/master

Comment: Maroun left out a step: `git fetch repo1` after `git remote add repo1 <url>`. Be careful with this, you may lose any or even all the commits you ever made in `repo2` here.

Comment: Thank you@Maroun and @torek! That gets the contents and luckly the changes are kept. However, I could not push in gerrit as I am getting  ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/master (no common ancestry). Is there a way forward with this?

Comment: I don't know anything about this aspect of Gerrit. I would point out that you never even mentioned Gerrit in the original question. This may be an instance of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @torek Thanks! The `tmp` branch hack is something that I find myself doing a lot (especially when I reset a branch that I'd like to apply changes to it later). Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: @Maroun: the `tmp` hack just saves the commit hash ID (which also saves the commit itself, in case `git gc` kicks in at a bad time). Overall it's probably the way to go, unless you prefer to use a tag instead of a branch—either way you get the same effect. The alternative is to save the hash ID somewhere outside Git, but if you do that and `git gc` kicks in at a bad time, that's when you lose your commits 

Comment: @torek My thoughts now validated :) Thanks for clarifying.